# pop-mark not working as expected

Tags: mark, mark-ring

I have some sample code like this:

```
(defun some-function ()
  (interactive)
  (push-mark)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  ; do some stuff
  (pop-mark))
```

Now I'm expecting pop-mark to get me back to the original location. But that doesn't seem to be happening. Any idea on how to do this properly ?

Comment: I would recommend storing your location points in let-bound variables and then going back there again:  `(let* ((point-one (point)) point-two) (goto-char (point-min)) [do stuff . . .] (goto-char point-one))`  You can create a place holder for the variable -- e.g., `point-two` and then when you get there, set it with `(setq point-two (point))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `pop-mark`'s documentation:  `...This does not move point in the buffer`

I think you want:

```
;; do some stuff
(goto-char (mark))
(pop-mark)
```

But if all you care about is returning to a previous location, and not actually using the mark ring, then you could either

1) save `(point)` in a variable and return to it

2) use `save-excursion` which does this for you

Comment: `save-excursion` really is the best way to do this. You don't have to worry about saving the initial position of point, just let `save-excursion` do the work for you.